# How to mock instance method

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-core, moq, xunit

I'm new to xunit and unit testing , I'm writing unit test which calls instance method from the implemented method of an Interface i.e While testing SendFaxAsEmail(..) method I want to mock the behavior of instance method SendEmail(..) which will return boolean. Below is the code

```
public class NPFaxAsEmailBL : INPFaxEmailBL
{
    private IEmailSender _emailSender;
   
    public NPFaxAsEmailBL(IEmailSender emailSender)
    {
        _emailSender = emailSender;
    }

    public bool SendFaxAsEmail(FaxMailDTO faxMailDTO)
    {
        bool isEmailSuccessfully = false;
        bool validationCompleted = CompleteValidation(faxMailDTO);
        if (validationCompleted)
        {
            Log.Information($"{faxMailDTO?.NP}: FaxAsMailRequest Request validation Completed.");
            
            faxMailDTO.ToAddressDisplayName = string.Format(GlobalConstant.EmailToFormat, faxMailDTO?.FaxNumber, faxMailDTO?.ReceiverName, faxMailDTO?.NP, faxMailDTO?.OTP);
            faxMailDTO.Subject = string.Empty;
            faxMailDTO.Body = string.Empty;
            faxMailDTO.FromAddressDisplayName = string.Empty;
            faxMailDTO.FromEmailAddress = AppSettingsHelper.FromEmailAddress;
            faxMailDTO.ToEmailAddress = AppSettingsHelper.ToEmailAddress;
            isEmailSuccessfully = SendEmail(AppSettingsHelper.RightFaxSMTPServer, faxMailDTO);
        }
            return isEmailSuccessfully;
    }

    public bool SendEmail(string sMTPServerUrl, FaxMailDTO faxAsMailRequest)
    {
        // return boolean value 
    }
}
```

When I execute below written test case it throws an error:

> System.NotSupportedException : Unsupported expression: x => x.SendEmail(NPFaxAsEmailTest.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.sMTPServerUrl, NPFaxAsEmailTest.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.faxMailDTO)
> Non-overridable members (here: NPFaxAsEmailBL.SendEmail) may not be used in setup / verification expressions.

```
public class NPFaxAsEmailTest
{
    private NPFaxAsEmailBL _nPFaxAsEmailBL;
    private Mock<IEmailSender> mock;
    private Mock<NPFaxAsEmailBL> _mockNPFaxAsEmailBL;

    public NPFaxAsEmailTest()
    {
        mock = new Mock<IEmailSender>();
        _nPFaxAsEmailBL = new NPFaxAsEmailBL(mock.Object);
        _mockNPFaxAsEmailBL = new Mock<NPFaxAsEmailBL>();
    }
    
    [Theory]
    [MemberData(nameof(GetFaxAsMailDTO))]
    public void SendFaxAsEmailTest_ReturnsTrue(FaxMailDTO faxMailDTO)
    {
        string sMTPServerUrl = AppSettingsHelper.RightFaxSMTPServer;
        _mockNPFaxAsEmailBL.Setup(x => x.SendEmail(sMTPServerUrl, faxMailDTO)).Returns(true); //<-this line throws an error
        var result=_nPFaxAsEmailBL.SendFaxAsEmail(faxMailDTO);
        Assert.True(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have to mock a public method from the class you're trying to test, you're doing it wrong. There is no relation between your `_nPFaxAsEmailBL` and `_mockNPFaxAsEmailBL`, the call to `SendFaxAsEmail()` on the former will not end up in the `SendEmail()` method of the latter.

Comment: @CodeCaster so what can I do in order to test SendFaxAsEmail() , because internally SendEmail shoots and email which i don't want while running the test case

Comment: You mock the part that actually sends the email, which would appear to be `_emailSender`.

Comment: @CodeCaster Basically I have written a different test case for SendEmail which just verify  _emailSender.SendEmail(emailContent) method . My intention was to test SendFaxAsEmail() ,could you tell me how would I do that

Comment: @VishalDhasal Could you please share with us the `SendEmail` and the `CompleteValidation` methods' bodies?